# PHP - Manupulation of strings

Tags: php, string

This is the raw data:

```
3
1/1.0
Question
Answer 1
Answer 2
....
Answer n
2
1/2.0
Question
Answer 1
Answer 2
....
Answer n
```

This is the desired output:

```
[ 
     3, 1.0, [],            
    "Question",
    [
        "Answer 1",
        "Answer 2",
        ....
        "Answer n"          
    ]               
],
[ 
     2, 2.0, [],            
    "Question",
    [
        "Answer 1",
        "Answer 2",
        ....
        "Answer n"          
    ]               
],
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
$step1 = str_replace("1/"," ", $raw);
$step2 = explode(PHP_EOL, $step1);
foreach ($step2 as $key => &$value) {   
    if(floatval($value) == 0) {
         $value = '"'.$value.'"';
    };
    $value = $value.",";
}
```

Now the tricky part: How to add the brackets and the tabs. 
I'm banging my head all day. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: so, this `"3, 1.0, []"` should be a single string value OR should they be separate array items?

Comment: hm, it doesn't matter as long as at the the end they are on a single line and separated by a space. Even if they are not on single line it is OK. 
Notice that they should not be in quotes. thank you,

Comment: so does my answer work for you? if yes , please mark as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$raw = "3
1/1.0
Question
Answer 1
Answer 2
....
Answer n
2
1/2.0
Question
Answer 1
Answer 2
....
Answer n";

$getAllLines = array_map("trim", explode("\n", $raw));
$endStr = "";
$nextIsQuestion = false;

foreach ($getAllLines as $getLine) {
    if (is_numeric($getLine)) {
        if (!empty($endStr)) {
            $endStr = substr($endStr, 0, -2) . "\n";
            $endStr .= "\t]\n],\n";
        }
        $endStr .= "[\n\t" . $getLine . ", ";
    }   
    else {
        if (strpos($getLine, "/") !== false) {
            $getNum = substr($getLine, strpos($getLine, "/") + 1);
            $endStr .= $getNum . ", [],\n\t";
            $nextIsQuestion = true;
        }
        elseif ($nextIsQuestion) {
            $endStr .= "\"" . $getLine . "\",\n\t[\n";
            $nextIsQuestion = false;
        }
        else {
            $endStr .= "\t\t\"" . $getLine . "\",\n";
        }
    }
}
$endStr = substr($endStr, 0, -2) . "\n";
$endStr .= "\t]\n]";

echo $endStr;
```

Output

```
[
        3, 1.0, [],
        "Question",
        [
                "Answer 1",
                "Answer 2",
                "....",
                "Answer n"
        ]
],
[
        2, 2.0, [],
        "Question",
        [
                "Answer 1",
                "Answer 2",
                "....",
                "Answer n"
        ]
]
```

Comment: thank you , that's a great answer , but some of the "Questions" and "Answers" contain numbers and slashes ("/") in them . And slashes break your script. Could it be fixed? 
What about an approach based on the order of the elements (Looks doable but can not succeed so far)?